# Transition probability matrix

Tags: self-study, markov-process, transition-matrix

A gambler tosses a coin and a tetrahedron at each stage. If $H$, he receives the amount appearing at the face of the tetrahedron. If $T$, he pays the amount. The tetrahedron is fair, but probability of $H$ is $2/3$. The game ends if he reaches $0$ or less wealth, or accumulates $6$ or more wealth.

I have tried making the transition probability matrix, but there's something wrong because the rows don't equal to 1. I think I didn't understand the problem well. Can someone explain to me how I could come up with the matrix without any knowledge of the amounts on the faces of the tetrahedron? Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can share the matrix you've found (together with some explanation) and we can comment. Otherwise, there are also other ways to solve the problem,

Comment: Even if you don't know what's written on the faces, you can give them names, such as "a", "b", etc.  But their names will never appear in the transition matrix, which contains only probabilities, and regardless of what's written on the tetrahedron, you know the probabilities from the assumption that it is fair.

Comment: @whuber Hi. Thanks for the explanation. So, regardless of the amount, the probability of each face of the tetrahedron is 1/4?

Comment: Many people would assume that.  You may answer the question more generally in terms of the probabilities associated with each face: that will introduce three more unknown real numbers into your answer (the fourth probability is determined by the other three, of course).